# Turtlebot bringup sci not available

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Tried three different computers, two different USB-2-Serial cables, but it never works. There is output on the screen, then a warning, followed by the iRobot Create being turned off with a single beep. Using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, with a Kinect on top of the iRobot Create.

[WARN] [WallTime: 1391659582.260008] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available

The irobot_create_2_1 bumpGo.py demo DOES however work, on the same system and hardware.

Full screen output here at gist.github.com / Alex-van-der-Peet / 8838247 (had to break it up, not allowed to post links). We set the environment variables specific to our robot:

export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect

Thanks,

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126641/turtlebot-bringup-sci-not-available/) by [elrapido80](https://answers.ros.org/users/11676/elrapido80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the create has timed out/turned itself off. SImilar question as here: http://answers.ros.org/question/161321/turtlebot_bringupwarncreate-robot-not-connected-yet-sci-not-available/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0